# Sequential name of column in a DataFrame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I work in python. 
I have a large DataFrame `df1` ( 25000 x 484 )  where, except than the first 4 columns, all the others can be divided in group of 4 and have sequential number. 
To be clear, non considering the first 4 columns, that's how the header of the columns look like:

**comp_type_1** / **tag_1** /**length_1**   / **value_1** / **comp_type_2** / **tag_2** /**length_2**   / **value_2** / **comp_type_3** / **tag_3** /**length_3**   / **value_3** ....

I would like to create  `df2` such that it contains only the column **lenght_i**, where i goes from 1 to the last number (120. Is there a way to realize that considering that part of the name of the column is the same, and what changes is only a number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this is what you're looking for.

```
# setup
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3, 12)), columns=["comp_type_1", "tag_1", "length_1", "value_1", "comp_type_2", "tag_2", "length_2", "value_2", "comp_type_3", "tag_3", "length_3", "value_3"])

# column filter 
df2 = df[[_ for _ in df.columns if 'length' in _]]
```

Output (`df2`)

```
    length_1    length_2    length_3
0   91          81          23
1   42          92          50
2   61          79          76
```

Answer (score 0):

Given dataframe `df` You can filter on columns:

```
df = df.filter(regex=("length"))
```